# Can I use one local git repo with two remote repo?

Tags: git, github

New to git and want to be sure I understand what I'm doing.

Currently, I have a local repo pushing to a public remote repo.
There are certain files and dir that I want to separate from the public remote repo and add to a private remote repo.

My plan is to add these files and dir to `.gitignore`, create a new branch named `privateRepo`, then link it to the private remote repo.  Afterwards, switch to the branch, `privateRepo` and add/commit/push the local contents.

```
git checkout -b privateRepo
git remote add privateRepo <url>
git switch privateRepo
git add <files & dir>
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

After this, I can use `git switch main` to return to my main branch and push without influencing `privateRepo`.

Is this correct?

Will this pose any problems if I want to pull from `privateRepo` to my local repo?

Comment: You do not switch to repos. You switch to _branches_.

Comment: I think putting private file into a submodule can be easier to manage

Comment: To answer the question title: Yes, see `git help remote`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* do what you're proposing.  I would advise against it because:

- it doesn't work the way I think you think it does; and
- it's far too easy to accidentally send the wrong commits to the wrong "other Git repository", thereby publishing forever your private files.

To understand this, we need to cover the basics of what a repository is and does for you.  A repository is, primarily, a collection of two databases:

- One database holds commits and other supporting Git objects.  This is the "object database".  It is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) in which the keys are *hash IDs*—commit hash IDs, and other supporting object hash IDs—and the values are the objects (the commits and the stuff commits use to store files forever).
- The other database holds *names*.  The keys in the object database—the hash IDs—are too big and ugly for humans to deal with.  So we don't: we use names.  Git keeps the second database around so that it can translate from name to hash ID, to find the commits (and other internal objects).  Humans can deal with names, like `master` or `main` as a branch name, for instance.

When you use more than one Git repository and cross-connect them with `git fetch` or `git push` (note that `git pull` is a convenience command that means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*, so it's really `git fetch` in disguise), what you're doing is transferring the *commits* between the repositories.  You have few options here: you either send a whole commit, or none of it.  You either receive a whole commit, or none of it.<sup>1</sup>  If you do send, or receive, a commit, you also send or receive *all its predecessor (ancestor) commits* that you or they don't have.<sup>2</sup>

The upshot of this is that if you accidentally send *one* commit to the wrong (i.e., public) repository, you'll likely send *all* of them.  Now they have every version of every private file you ever committed.  You *can* try to take this back—GitHub make this somewhat difficult as you must contact GitHub support—but during the window where these commits are visible, anyone and everyone can copy them from the public repository.

If you, instead, split the files into "public availability files"—which you put in one repository and then share that repository with GitHub as a public repository there—and "private files" that go into a *different repository*, and then share that one with GitHub only as a *private* repository, the whole thing is much more manageable.

You can coordinate the two repositories with Git's *submodules*, as [Ôrel mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69964586/can-i-use-one-local-git-repo-with-two-remote-repo#comment123677017_69964586).  Submodules have their own headaches and drawbacks, enough so that people sometimes call them *sob*-modules, but they do achieve a proper public/private split.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git is growing a new facility called *partial clones* where this general all-or-nothing principle is carefully pulled apart, like a [Jenga tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenga).  Pull the wrong part and the whole thing collapses, though.  This is not—at least currently—meant for the kind of thing you're talking about and I would not advise using it for that, unless you plan to work on Git itself to add that.  (It could in theory be used for this sort of purpose.)

<sup>2</sup>This rule, too, can be carefully violated with *shallow clones*.  Shallow clones are more mature than the partial clone code, but they still don't do the kind of thing you want.

---

#### Some more words about repositories

Many people think Git is about files.  It's not: it's really about *commits*.  The commits do, however, *hold* files.  Or they'll think that Git is about branches.  It's not: it's about commits.  The branch names, however, do help you (and Git) *find* the commits.  So branch names, and files, are important.  But it's really all about the commits.

Because commits are stored in the object database, they're *numbered*, with those big ugly hash IDs.  Every unique object gets a unique number.  The commit numbers in particular must be unique across *every Git repository in the universe*, which means the numbers must be huge (currently there are 2<sup>160</sup> possible numbers, and this will probably become 2<sup>256</sup> in the relatively near future as it turns out 2<sup>160</sup> is too small).  That's why they are so big and ugly and random-looking, though actually they're entirely non-random: they are outputs from a cryptographic hash function (currently SHA-1; SHA-256 is the planned future).

Each commit, though, stores *two* things:

- Every commit stores a full snapshot of every file, as of the form the file had at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.  These are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format (as objects in the database), not as ordinary computer files.
- Every commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself: who made it, when, and why (a log message) for instance.  This metadata is as read-only as everything in the objects database.  (The read-only quality comes from Git's hashing tricks, and is necessary to allow the file de-duplication as well.)

In the metadata for any one given commit, Git stores the raw hash ID(s) of a list of previous commit(s).  Usually this list is just one element long.  We call this single previous commit the *parent* of the commit.  These parent IDs form backwards-looking chains:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Commit `H` has, inside it, a full snapshot of all of your files, plus some metadata.  The metadata in `H` show you that you (or whoever) made the commit.  They keep data such as your log message.  And, they show that commit `H` has one parent, whatever hash ID `G` stands in for.

Commit `G`, of course, also has a snapshot and metadata.  Using `H`, Git can find `G`, and extract *both snapshots* and compare them.  Whatever is the same did not change (and this is easy for Git to see because of the de-duplication via hashing).  Whatever is different, here Git will need to run `git diff` to figure out *what changed*.  Git will do this if and when you ask for it, and you'll see what *changed* going from `G` to `H`, when you view commit `H`.

Having viewed commit `H`, a command like `git log` now moves back one hop to commit `G`.  Commit `G` has metadata, including the hash ID of earlier commit `F`.  Commit `F` has a snapshot, so Git can compare `F`-vs-`G` to see what changed, and hence show you `G` as changes, even though `G` *is* a snapshot.  Then `git log` can move back one hop to `F`, and repeat.  The process ends only when Git has gone back to the very first commit ever, which—being the first commit—has *no* parent, or when you get tired of reading `git log` output and make it quit.

#### Using commits: the work-tree and the index / staging-area

But there's a big problem here.  If the *content* in a snapshot, the saved-for-all-time files, is *read-only*—and, worse, in a format that only Git itself can read in the first place—how will we ever *use* it?

The answer to this problem is simple enough.  In a *non-bare* repository (which is to say, most of them), Git adds a *working area*, called a *working tree* or *work-tree*.  To use a commit, Git simply copies all the files *out of the commit*, into your working tree.  Now you can see your files and do your work.

It's important to realize that *these* files are *not in Git*.  These are ordinary computer files, that all your ordinary computer programs can read and write and generally work with.  They may have come *out of* Git.  But at this point, they're not *in* Git any more.  They're just files.

As you work with them, they may drift away from what's *in* Git.  Their contents change.  At some point, you might wish to take all the updated files and store them forever, in a new commit.  In other, non-Git, version control systems, this is pretty easy: you run, e.g., `hg commit` and Mercurial figures out what you changed and makes a new commit.  In Git, this is not so easy.

Instead, Git adds a hidden *extra "copy"* of each file.  I say "copy" in quotes here because this extra "copy" of each file is pre-Git-ified: it is stored in the compressed, de-duplicated format that Git uses internally.  Since all these files initially came *out* of some commit, they're all duplicates, and therefore none of them take any space.<sup>3</sup>

When you tell Git *make a new commit now*, Git looks only at these hidden extra copies.  So, before you *make* a new commit, you must run `git add`.  What `git add` does is:

- read through the working tree copy of some file;
- compress and generally Git-ify it, coming up with an internal object hash ID;
- if that's a duplicate of some existing file, throw out the temporary stuff built up now and use the duplicate;
- otherwise, prep it for future committing and store it.

Either way, the `git add` step takes the updated file and makes it ready to go into the next commit.  This *replaces* the copy that *was there*, ready to go into the next commit.  Or, if the file is all-new—if there was no file with this name before—then `git add` has nothing to replace, and instead adds a new file, and now there is a copy, ready to go into the next commit.

In all cases, then, *before* `git add`, Git had all the files ready to go into the new commit.  *After* `git add`, Git has all the files ready to go into the new commit.  So Git *always* has all the files ready to go.  What `git add` does is replace one, or two, or many, of those ready-to-go "copies" with updated files (new copies if needed, or re-used old "copies" if possible) and add any new files.

The area in which this extra ready-to-go not-quite-a-commit-yet thing lives has *three* names in Git.  This may be because the primary name, the *index*, is meaningless.  The other main name, the *staging area*, refers to how you *use* the index.  The third name, the *cache*, is mostly defunct, but still shows up in flags like `git rm --cached`.  I tend to use the name "index", but "staging area" has probably become the most common, and it's definitely how you use it: you "stage" the files by arranging them on/in a "staging area", ready to be "photographed" into a commit where they will live forever.

This staging area, or index, sits between the current commit and your working tree.  Git's index is a lot like a commit, and is initially set up *from* a commit and later *becomes a new commit*, but the key difference between an actual commit and Git's index is that you can *replace files in, add files to, and remove files from* Git's index.  You can't do that to a commit: the commit, once made, is set in stone.

When you do finally run `git commit`, Git simply packages up the files that are in the index *right then*.  Those become the snapshot for the new commit.  So you must *update the index*.  People are often tempted by `git commit -a`, but there are some flaws with this and I advise users to avoid it (see below).

In any case, I find that it helps, to think of the index as being *between* commit and working tree, like this:

```
  HEAD         index      work-tree
---------    ---------    ---------
README.md    README.md    README.md
main.py      main.py      main.py
                          new.txt
```

Here, we checked out some commit that had two files in it, so `HEAD`—the current commit—has those two files, and Git's index has those two files, and our working tree has those two files.  Unlike the HEAD and index copies, we can actually see and *use* the working tree copies, but all three exist.

Then we made a *new file*, `new.txt`, in the working tree.  It doesn't exist in `HEAD`, and it doesn't exist in Git's index.  Now we come to an interesting special case.

---

<sup>3</sup>They take some space for name, hash ID, and a bunch of cache data that Git uses internally.  The amount of space needed depends on the name lengths and the index format (there are multiple index format numbers) but it's generally pretty tiny, on the order of 100 bytes per file.

---

#### Tracked, untracked, and ignored files

The new file we made in the working tree *is not in Git*.  Neither are the two other files we can see, but those two *do* have *copies* that *are* in Git, in the `HEAD` commit, and a proposed *new* commit prepared in the index.  But `new.txt` is not in the index: it's not even in the proposed next commit.

At this point, `new.txt` is what Git calls an *untracked file*.  An untracked file is defined as *any file that is not in Git's index right now*.

Suppose, for instance, that we now run:

```
git rm --cached main.py
```

to produce this:

```
  HEAD         index      work-tree
---------    ---------    ---------
README.md    README.md    README.md
main.py                   main.py
                          new.txt
```

We didn't change the commit (we can't change its contents), but now `main.py` is *not in Git's index right now*.  The `main.py` in our working tree has gone from *tracked* to *untracked*.

If we run `git add main.py new.txt` right now, Git will:

- read the contents of `main.py`, compress them, and discover it's a duplicate and re-use the old `main.py` in the index;
- read the contents of `new.txt`, compress them, and probably discover it's new and make a new Git-ified copy prepared for commit, and put that in the index;

and now we will have:

```
  HEAD         index      work-tree
---------    ---------    ---------
README.md    README.md    README.md
main.py      main.py      main.py
             new.txt      new.txt
```

Now we have *no* untracked files.

**The tracked-ness of a file is changeable.**  All we have to do is create or remove index entries and/or working tree files.  Those files that are in *both* are *tracked files;* those files that are only in the working tree are *untracked files*.  And that's all there is to that—**almost**.

#### Why `.gitignore` does not mean what people think it means

A file that is in Git's index is *never ignored*.

An entry in `.gitignore`, listing a file's name, tells Git, in part, *if this file is untracked, don't **complain** about it.*  The `git status` command is very useful, as it will tell us about what's in the index and what's not in the index, in terms of stuff we have forgotten to `git add` for instance.  That includes any *file* that's in the working tree, but not in the index.

But some things—like Python 2.x—generate a lot of working tree files that *should never be committed*.  If `git status` complained about all your `*.pyc` files all the time, `git status` could become unusable: the useful nuggets of "oh I forgot to `git add` this one thing" would be buried in the useless "here are 5000 `*.pyc` files you could add" messages.

To prevent this, we list the `*.pyc` *glob pattern* in a `.gitignore` file.  This makes `git status` shut up about these files.

It has one other effect as well.  We can run `git add .` or `git add --all` or similar to do an en-masse "add everything".  When we *do* use this, Git will *skip* any existing untracked file that's also listed in `.gitignore`.  But Git only skips the *untracked* files, not the tracked ones.  The tracked files—the ones that *are* in Git's index—get updated.  (This is actually usually what people want.)

So, `.gitignore` is the wrong name.  The file should be named something like `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-files-when-they-are-untracked-and-also-if-they-are-untracked-and-I-use-an-en-masse-git-add-command-do-not-add-them-to-the-index-after-all`.  But this name is ridiculous, as are several slightly shorter versions.  So it's just called `.gitignore`.

The key here is that it *won't* ignore files that *are* in the index.  For a file to go into a commit, it has to be *in Git's index*.  If it was in a commit and we checked the commit out, the file is now *in Git's index*.  So once a file gets committed, it tends to sneak back into the index, even if we take it out now and then: any time we check out a commit that *has* the file, it's back in the index.  And then its listing in `.gitignore` has no effect.

#### Why (and when) to avoid `git commit -a`

What `git commit -a` does is use a shortcut.  It:

- runs `git add` *for you*, and then
- does the `git commit` step.

You can also do things like:

```
git commit --only main.py
```

and:

```
git commit --include main.py
```

These all manipulate the index, then do the commit.  However, they're quite tricky: they make Git make one or two *extra and temporary* index files for the duration of the commit.  These extra index files *can* mess with pre-commit hooks.  Whether, and when, and how much, they *do* mess with such hooks depends on several things, including how carefully the hook writer wrote their hook, whether they were even aware of this Git trick, and whether you use the `--only` or `--include` form of `git commit`.<sup>4</sup>

That said, `git commit -a` usually works fine (see footnote 4).  But it is roughly equivalent to running `git add -u` first, and then running `git commit`.  The `-u` option to `git add` will only *update known files*, not *add new ones*.  When we use `git add .` to en-masse add *everything* we've updated, this includes adding new files.  The `-a` option to `git commit` *can't* add a *new* file.

Besides this, `git commit -a` is just plain lazy.  Sometimes laziness is a virtue, so this doesn't mean *never* use it.  But `git status`, followed by careful `git add` operations—perhaps even `git add -p` operations—followed by another `git status`, followed by `git diff --cached` (or `git diff --staged`—these do exactly the same thing), will help you arrange to commit *only the changes you want*.  Reading through the diff lets you compose a good commit message, or take notes at least, in another window, which you can then paste into the commit.  This lets you make *good, careful commits*.  To do this, you must generally avoid `git commit -a`.  So it's at least a bad *habit*, even if laziness is occasionally a virtue.

---

<sup>4</sup>`git commit -a` uses the `--include` mode internally.  This is less disruptive than the `--only` form, because `--include` needs only *two* index files, not three, and the one used during the commit is the one that becomes the new index after the commit if the commit succeeds.  The extra file is used only for the rollback case.  The `--only` form needs three: one for the commit, one for rollback, and one for success; all three have—at least potentially—different content.

Comment: If I understand you explanation, once a file is committed, there will forever be a committed copy.  Even if that file is no longer tracked, a copy of it will exist simply by having been previously tracked and committed.
So if a file has not yet been tracked/staged, adding said file to ```.gitignore``` can prevent a reminder about staging (or auto stage) it  and thus the file will not be committed (unless I manually add it to a commit).

Comment: Right - or more precisely, the committed copy lasts as long as the commit itself persists. It's hard, but not impossible, to remove commits (and once sent to GitHub you have to get GitHub support to do that), so one can think of commits as being "for all time". If the file's never been staged or committed, listing it in `.gitignore` prevents *accidentally* adding it: you have to add with `--force` to override the `.gitignore` instructions. But if it never goes into a commit, it's never in Git in the first place.